# How does Python interpret this statement as True?

Tags: python, if-statement

The following is a part of code RockPaperScissors, I can't figure out how Python, interpret

```
if answer in ("y", "yes", "Y", "Yes", "Of course"):
    return answer
```

since this return as a True.

and this other part of code below returns an Integer

```
player = int(player)
if player in (1, 2, 3):
    return player
```

How is it possible that it returns True for one part and an Integer in otherpart since it is the same structure?

based on the code below:

```
def start():
    print "Let's play a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors"
    while game():
        pass
    scores()

def game():
    player = move()
    computer = random.randint(1, 3)
    result(player, computer)
    return play_again()

def move():
    while True:
        print
        player = raw_input("Rock = 1\nPaper = 2\nScissors = 3\nMake a move : ")
        try:
            player = int(player)
            if player in (1, 2, 3):
                return player
        except ValueError:
            print "Oops ! I didn't understand that, Please enter 1, 2 or 3."

def result(player, computer):
    print "1..."
    time.sleep(1)
    print "2..."
    time.sleep(1)
    print "3 !"
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print "Computer threw {0}!".format(names[computer])
    global player_score, computer_score
    if player == computer:
        print "Tie game"
    else:
        if rules[player] == computer:
            print "victory getting closer !"
            player_score += 1

def play_again():
    answer = raw_input("Would you like to play again ?")
    if answer in ("y", "yes", "Y", "Yes", "Of course"):
        return True
    else:
        print "ok that's enough for today !"

def scores():
    global player_score, computer_score
    print "HIGH SCORES"
    print "Player : " + player_score
    print "Computer :" + computer_score
```

Comment: Why is that puzzling? The `answer in (...)` test is only true if the value in `answer` is also in that tuple.

Comment: i edited back my question, hope you understand my concern

Comment: Neither code returns `True`. It returns the value of `answer` in one case, the value of `player` in the other case. `play_again()` returns `None` if the `if` statement was never true; a non-empty string is considered true, and `None` is considered false. So `play_again()` either returns one of those strings (`'y'`, `'Y'`, etc.) or it returns `None`, and those two objects have different [truth values](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you think that `return answer` returns `True`. It does not.

It returns the value of `answer`, which will be a non-empty string equal to one of the strings in the tuple. So the function `play_again()` returns `'Y'` if you typed that in, because `'Y'` is in the tuple.

When `answer` has a value that is *not* in the list, the `if` suite is not executed, so the `else:` branch prints a message and the function ends without a `return` statement. Python then returns `None` instead.

So `play_again()` either returns a non-empty string, one that is a member of the tuple `("y", "yes", "Y", "Yes", "Of course")`, **or** it returns `None`. `game()` returns that value unchanged, back to the `while` loop in `start()`:

```
while game():
    pass
```

The `while` statement [tests the truth value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) of the return value. A non-empty string is considered true (so the loop continues), and `None` is considered false (the loop ends).

Answer (score 4):

If `answer` is an element of `("y", "yes", "Y", "Yes", "Of course")`, then that evaluates to `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on user input (which could be `yes` or `no`) assigned to variable `answer` Python checks to see this variable appears in `("y", "yes", "Y", "Yes", "Of course")`.

It's a little syntactic sugar.

You could also do:

```
for x in ("y", "yes", "Y", "Yes", "Of course"):
    if answer == x:
        return answer
```

More info on the python operands (e.g. `is`, `is not` and `not in`) in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in).

Answer (score 0):

`answer in ("y", "yes", "Y", "Yes", "Of course")` evaluates to `True` if `answer` is equal to any of `("y", "yes", "Y", "Yes", "Of course")`'s elements.